# Installing previous versions of a formula with brew extract

Tags: homebrew

Due to a [problem](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/53193) with the Subversion 1.13 Brew formula I was installing an older revision of the formula:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0c3d786402ad7d9dd5eb6907e3ed3f2525a0472d/Formula/subversion.rb
```

That gives a warning:

```
Warning: Calling Installation of subversion from a GitHub commit URL is deprecated! Use 'brew extract subversion' to stable tap on GitHub instead.
```

The suggestion is the same as [this tip](https://docs.brew.sh/Tips-N%27-Tricks#installing-previous-versions-of-formulae).

Now, I'd like to do this properly using `brew extract subversion` rather than using the deprecated commit URL. I'd like to install Subversion 1.13_5 on some computers, but Subversion 1.14 is the latest formula.

I need to do something like this: `brew extract --version 1.13.0_5 subversion <tap>`.

The way I understand this I should:

1. Create an empty repository for my versioned formulas
2. Add the repository as a tap and initialize it
3. Extract the versioned formula
4. Commit and push the formula?

I created an [empty repository](https://github.com/rjollos/homebrew-versioned), then:

```
$ brew tap rjollos/homebrew-versioned
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/rjollos/homebrew-versioned'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Tapped (16 files, 22.2KB).
$ brew tap-new rjollos/homebrew-versioned
==> Created rjollos/versioned
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/rjollos/homebrew-versioned
$ brew extract --version '1.13.0_5' subversion rjollos/homebrew-versioned
==> Searching repository history
Warning: Calling 'devel' blocks in formulae is deprecated! Use 'head' blocks or @-versioned formulae instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/subversion.rb:16

Warning: Calling 'devel' blocks ... (repeats about a dozen times)

Error: subversion: undefined method `sha1' for #<SoftwareSpec:0x00007fceaf144490>
```

I think I'm doing several things wrong, but mainly I'm unsure why `brew extract` doesn't work. Also, is there a better way to create a new repository and populate it with the template files for a new tap?

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.4.4-19-ge09802b
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 5ee797; last commit 2020-07-07)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 837ac; last commit 2020-07-08)
```

Comment: Described in [Homebrew #7948](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7948), version should be `1.13.0` rather than `1.13.0_5`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Still not sure this is the best way to create a new tap. I created `homebrew-repo` on my GitHub, then added the tap, then initialized the tap using `tap-new`.

```sh
$ TAP=rjollos/homebrew-repo
$ TAP_PATH=$(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/$TAP

$ brew tap $TAP
==> Tapping rjollos/repo
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/rjollos/homebrew-repo'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Tapped (16 files, 22.2KB).

$ brew tap-new $TAP
==> Created rjollos/repo
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/rjollos/homebrew-repo

$ cd $TAP_PATH

$ git add .

$ git commit -m "Initialized with template files"
[master (root-commit) c7c4bed] Initialized with template files
 2 files changed, 29 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .github/workflows/main.yml
 create mode 100644 README.md

$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/rjollos/homebrew-repo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/rjollos/homebrew-repo (push)
```

Extract the versioned formula:

```sh
$ brew extract --version 1.13.0 subversion $TAP
==> Searching repository history
==> Writing formula for subversion from revision dab5452 to:
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/rjollos/homebrew-repo/Formula/subversion@1.13.0.rb
```

Add the formula:

```sh
$ cd $TAP_PATH
$ git add Formula
$ git commit -m "Add Subversion 1.13 formula"
 1 file changed, 203 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 Formula/subversion@1.13.0.rb
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 3.99 KiB | 2.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/rjollos/homebrew-repo
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Fantastic step and documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 67):

Taps can be created locally without actual github repository. Here is general example:

```sh
TAP=...     # <org>/<repo>, for example "my-org/homebrew-old"
MODULE=...  # name of module you want to install, e.g. "hugo"
VERS=...    # version of $MODULE you want to install, e.g., "0.80.0"
brew tap-new $TAP
brew extract --version $VERS $MODULE $TAP
brew install $TAP/$MODULE@$VERS
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly without any issues 

Comment: Might help to clarify that `<org>/<repo>` is something you make up, not `homebrew/core`, etc.

Comment: I get `Unsupported special dependency :java` error while installing antlr 4.7.2

Comment: Was very excited to try this but didn't work for me:

Comment: It seems to only work for recent versions 

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach to get around the error and install from a specific formula file:

```bash
curl -o subversion.rb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0c3d786402ad7d9dd5eb6907e3ed3f2525a0472d/Formula/subversion.rb
brew install -s subversion.rb
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried `brew install <url>` approach, seems working well for me?

installation log:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/0c3d786402ad7d9dd5eb6907e3ed3f2525a0472d/Formula/subversion.rb
Warning: Calling Installation of subversion from a GitHub commit URL is deprecated! Use 'brew extract subversion' to stable tap on GitHub instead.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/subversion-1.13.0_5.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/rchen/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6c15ae92fb6a09985f1679367588188829b69a4dbc53bb324597fb9fdf588d9e--subversion-1.13.0_5.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: subversion 1.14.0_2 is available and more recent than version 1.13.0_5.
==> Pouring subversion-1.13.0_5.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
svntools have been installed to:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/libexec

The perl bindings are located in various subdirectories of:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5

You may need to link the Java bindings into the Java Extensions folder:
  sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/Extensions
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.13.0_5: 234 files, 30.3MB
Removing: /Users/rchen/Library/Caches/Homebrew/subversion--1.13.0_5.mojave.bottle.tar.gz... (8.6MB)
```

version check

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.13.0 (r1867053)
   compiled Apr 17 2020, 12:01:27 on x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0

Copyright (C) 2019 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.9 (compiled with 1.3.9)
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

The following authentication credential caches are available:

* Mac OS X Keychain
```

Comment: It does work. And you received the same warning that I did: `Warning: Calling Installation of subversion from a GitHub commit URL is deprecated! Use 'brew extract subversion' to stable tap on GitHub instead.`

Comment: I do have another hacky way which mentioned in here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62765875/791609, either way would do the same thing.

Comment: It sounds to me like `brew extract` is the new and proper way to create a versioned formula, avoiding the tricks we used in the past, but I haven't found any step-by-step documentation on creating a formula.

Comment: That is a good feedback, I can play around it this weekend. I have not used `brew extract <xx>`before though , TBH.

Comment: I created an issue for the problem I encountered, possible defect in `brew`: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7948.

Comment: Described in [Homebrew #7948](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7948), version should be `1.13.0` rather than `1.13.0_5`. I've posted an updated answer.