# Trying to install Hugo via Homebrew - "Could Not Resolve HEAD to a Revision"

Tags: git, homebrew, hugo

I'm trying to take a stab at a new site using Hugo, and I am stuck during installation. I've installed Homebrew and when running the version, I get the following:

```
~ % brew --version
Homebrew 2.7.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (no git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision b96680c; last commit 2021-01-07)
```

And when I run `brew install hugo`

I get the following:

```
~ % brew install hugo
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "hugo".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

What am I doing wrong? This is the first time working in home-brew.

---

Edit: when running `brew install --verbose Hugo`, I get the following warnings:

```
% brew install --verbose hugo

fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...

Error: No similarly named formulae found.

Error: No available formula or cask with the name "hugo".

==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...

Error: No previously deleted formula found.

==> Searching taps on GitHub...

/usr/bin/curl --disable --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/2.7.2\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 11.1\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --location https://api.github.com/search/code\?q=user\%3AHomebrew\+path\%3AFormula\+path\%3ACasks\+path\%3A.\+filename\%3Ahugo\+extension\%3Arb\&per_page=100 --header Accept:\ application/vnd.github.v3\+json --write-out '
'\%\{http_code\} --header Accept:\ application/vnd.github.antiope-preview\+json --header Authorization:\ token\ ****** --dump-header /private/tmp/github_api_headers20210106-8376-1r02uaz
```

Comment: Try `brew doctor`?

Comment: I get a few warnings but no errors. Updated question to reflect.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Use

```sh
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master
```

or

```sh
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: If the `checkout master` is raising some errors, you might need to explicitly specify the remote (ex. `origin`), as in `git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout origin/master`. Use `git remote -v` to get the remote name. See this for why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch

Comment: It was useful for me, thank @Gino Mempin

Comment: Confirmed this worked for M1 Macbook Air.

Comment: It works on macbook pro 2021. THANK YOU

Comment: This works. Can I get any explanation on this answer ? What did it do? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As illustrated by [this thread](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/running-brew-update-returns-error-fatal-could-not-resolve-head-to-a-revision/7528/3), this might be related to `brew` itself, not so much `hugo`.

```
brew install --verbose hugo
```

This should give you more and allow you to see at which step brew is stuck.

> [where the error occurred], I changed into that directory to find that it was empty – all that was in the dir was a `.git/` folder and nothing else.
>
> So, to restore the missing contents, I used `git fetch` and `git pull --rebase`.

---

```
No available formula or cask with the name "hugo".
```

That points to a brew configuration issue, since there is a [formulae](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md) for [hugo](https://github.com/Homebrew/formulae.brew.sh/blob/master/_data/formula/hugo.json)

> Packages are installed according to their formulae, which live in `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula`

Check that `Formula` folder and see if `hugo` is missing there.
If not, at least try `brew extract hugo` inside [a new tap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64125796/6309).

```sh
brew tap-new gohugoio/hugo
brew extract --version 0.80.0 hugo gohugoio/hugo
brew install gohugoio/hugo/hugo@0.80.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Set your core by running the below two commands

1. rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
2. brew tap homebrew/core

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. I tried most solutions above. In the end these steps helped:

#### uninstall homebrew

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`

#### manually delete this file and the two folders

`/usr/local/com.apple.installer.keep`

`/usr/local/Homebrew`

`/usr/var/homebrew`

#### install homebrew again

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 0):

run `brew doctor`

and the output:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core

Warning: Some taps are not on the default git origin branch and may not receive
updates. If this is a surprise to you, check out the default branch with:
  git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

follow the instruction which under the warning, everything seems resolved.