# installing php by homebrew shows "fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision"?

Tags: php, homebrew, php-8

I run command "brew install php" it throughs error

```
    fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> New Casks
clock-signal               duplicate-file-finder      memory-cleaner
==> Updated Casks
Updated 166 casks.
==> Deleted Casks
adafruit-arduino                         blue-jeans-browser-plugin
adobe-lens-profile-creator               caramba-switcher
beautune

Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "php".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Plese help me

and thanks for helping me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to install Hugo via Homebrew - "Could Not Resolve HEAD to a Revision"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605282/trying-to-install-hugo-via-homebrew-could-not-resolve-head-to-a-revision)

Comment: Please include a complete output.

Comment: please explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `brew doctor` for see warnings and errors about it.
In my case I solved it by removing Taps dir

```
rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
```

and

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

and try run again `brew install php@7.4` or your version