# unable to install maven on macbook pro (fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision)

Tags: macos, homebrew

trying to install maven using brew install maven

getting bellow error

```
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "maven".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605282/trying-to-install-hugo-via-homebrew-could-not-resolve-head-to-a-revision help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following commands:

brew doctor

git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master

Comment: sure let me try this